# Codeigniter high controller execution time

Tags: php, performance, codeigniter

I have some problem with codeigniter controller.
Sometimes my page will load in [image: super fast load]

but sometimes will load in:
[image: super slow load]

I can't post the code because i can't post code from site
My question is what i can do to see where is the problem and what is loading so slow 
Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you will have to start [Profiling your code](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html) So you can work out where the bottleneck is

Comment: Does the controller perform any actions which can be affected by external factors such as curl requests, database connections, SQL executions, connecting to ADUC, connecting to Exchange, API consumption, local file reading/writing, or network file access?

Comment: I have some program in C# which makes some webrequest to server (webrequest.create()). @MonkeyZeus

Comment: @VladutZzZ Ok, so is that C# code executing quickly or slowly? How is this code executed, using `exec();` in PHP?

Comment: I am running into similar.  I don't notice that extreme, but I do notice 5-10 seconds for executive time.  I have tested the loading and query performance (using profiler and benchmarking) and can confirm those are not the issue.  This doesn't happen every time, just when the system has been dormant for a bit.